# How to get entries from tableA which have no entry in tableB? (SQL)

Tags: mysql, sql

In mysql I have `tableA` with rows `userid` and `valueA` and `tableB` with `userid` and `valueB`.

Now I want all entries from `tableA` which don't have an entry in `tableB` with the same `userid`.

I tried several things but can't figure out what I do wrong.

```
SELECT * FROM `tableA`
left join `tableB` on `tableA`.`userid` = `tableB`.`userid`
```

This is a very good start actually. It gives me all entries from `tableA` + the corresponding values from `tableB`. If they don't exist they are displayed as `NULL` (in phpmyadmin).

```
SELECT * FROM `tableA`
left join `tableB` on `tableA`.`userid` = `tableB`.`userid`
where `tableB`.`valueB` = NULL
```

Too bad, empty result. Maybe this would have been too easy. (By the way: `tableA` has ~10k entries and `tableB` has ~7k entries with `userid` being unique in each. No way the result would be empty if it would do what I want it to do)

```
SELECT * FROM `tableA`
left join `tableB` on `tableA`.`userid` = `tableB`.`userid`
where `tableA`.`userid` != `tableB`.`userid`
```

This doesn't work either, and to be honest it also looks totally paradox. Anyways, I'm clueless now. Why didn't my 2nd query work and what is a correct solution?

Comment: Try `where \`tableB\`.\`valueB\` IS NULL` had this issue before too.

Comment: Your second query is SO, SO close. Just change the `= NULL` to `IS NULL`.  Consider doing that test on the userid column, if the valueB column can contain null (if what you really want is rows from A that don't have a matching row in B.)  See my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are almost there. That second query is SO close! All it needs is one little tweak:

Instead of "`= NULL`"  you need an "`IS NULL`" in the predicate.

```
SELECT * FROM `tableA`
left join `tableB` on `tableA`.`userid` = `tableB`.`userid`
where `tableB`.`valueB` IS NULL
                        ^^
```

Note that the equality comparison operator `=` will return NULL (rather than TRUE or FALSE) when one side (or both sides) of the comparison are NULL. (In terms of relational databases and SQL, boolean logic has three values, rather than two: TRUE, FALSE and NULL.)

BTW... the pattern in your query, the outer join with the test for the NULL on the outer joined table)  is commonly referred to as an "anti-join" pattern. The usual pattern is to test the same column (or columns) that were referred to in the JOIN condition, or a column that has a NOT NULL constraint, to avoid ambiguous results. (for example, what if 'ValueB' can have a NULL value, and we did match a row.  Nothing wrong with that at all, it just depends on whether you want that row returned or not.)

If you are looking for rows in tableA that do NOT have a matching row in tableB, we'd generally do this:

```
SELECT * FROM `tableA`
left join `tableB` on `tableA`.`userid` = `tableB`.`userid`
where `tableB`.`userid` IS NULL
                ^^^^^^  ^^
```

Note that the IS NULL test is on the **`userid`** column, which is guaranteed to be "not null" if a matching rows was found.  (If the column had been NULL, the row would not have satisfied the equality test in the JOIN predicate.

Answer (score 1):

Change `= NULL` for `IS NULL` on your code. You can also use `NOT EXISTS` instead:

```
SELECT * 
FROM `tableA` A
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM `tableB`
                  WHERE `userid` = A.`userid`)
```

Answer (score 0):

this will help explain the use of working with NULL values:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/working-with-null.html

Answer (score 0):

the less expensive query would be this, all the other queries sugested are too expensive if the database is too big:

```
SELECT * FROM tableA a 
   WHERE a.userid NOT IN
     (SELECT  b.user_id FROM tableB b);
```

Comment: That's weird. I have read that JOINs are always faster than using subqueries?

Comment: where you read the information was wrong, specially because the word **always** was used. You should **write the query that logically fits the best whatever what you are trying to do**, and leave the optimizations to the SQL optimizer if you have no idea of what your doing and what performs best in your database structure.